# Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint error when trying to insert valid data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a unique constraint on a table that was created as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.AccessIntegrationSettings ADD CONSTRAINT ucAccessIntegrationSettings UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
    (
        [AccessIntegrationPartnerSys] ASC,
        [AccessIntegrationSettingEnum] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Currently, in the table, there is only one record, and the two columns in question have values as follows:

```
AccessIntegrationPartnerSys     AccessIntegrationSettingEnum
------------------------------------------------------------
       100000                               1
```

Now, I am trying to do the following insert:

```
INSERT INTO AccessIntegrationSettings (AccessIntegrationPartnerSys, AccessIntegrationSettingEnum)
VALUES
(100000, 13)
```

But I get the following error:

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'ucAccessIntegrationSettings'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AccessIntegrationSettings'. The duplicate key value is (100000, `<NULL>`).

I don't understand why I am getting this error. First, I am not trying to insert duplicate values.  And second, I'm unsure why the second value in the error message is showing as NULL.

Comment: Do you have a trigger on that table running?

Comment: No.  No triggers

Comment: Is the error actually occurring on the `INSERT` or the `ALTER ` command. I suspect it is the later and you are running both commands in the same batch.

Comment: The error happens on the INSERT. I can only insert one row.  If I try to insert any other rows, I get an error.  I would assume I did something wrong in creating the constraint, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: I may just remove the constraint and just have to rely on the code in the app to not insert rows with a duplicate combination of those two columns.

Comment: What is the type of `AccessIntegrationSettingEnum`? I suspect that `13` is an invalid value for this type, hence `NULL` is insrted instead of `13` the first time you try to `INSERT`. The second time you get the error message you mention, because `NULL` is, for SQL Server, a value that cannot be repeated in a unique field.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos... AccessIntegrationSettingEnum is an INT. The type is valid.

Comment: If you query your table using `select * from AccessIntegrationSettings  where AccessIntegrationPartnerSys  = 100000` what is the result that you get?

Comment: when you do `select * from dbo.AccessIntegrationSettings` do you see both columns filled ? there is no record with a null value in the second column ?

Comment: does table `AccessIntegrationSettings` also exist in another schema then `dbo` ? Can you try to set dbo. also in the insert statement

Comment: @GuidoG, yes, that's the odd thing. When I do a select, both columns are filled, as in the example above in the OP.  No NULL values.

Comment: You're applying UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED on both columns, and trying to INSERT 100000 in AccessIntegrationPartnerSys, while there is already a value of 100000 exists. That's why you get this violation error. you either insert a different number or remove the unique from AccessIntegrationPartnerSys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed to creation of the constraint from:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.AccessIntegrationSettings ADD CONSTRAINT ucAccessIntegrationSettings UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
    (
        [AccessIntegrationPartnerSys] ASC,
        [AccessIntegrationSettingEnum] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

to:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME ='ucAccessIntegrationSettings')
    ALTER TABLE dbo.AccessIntegrationSettings ADD CONSTRAINT ucAccessIntegrationSettings UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
    (
        [AccessIntegrationPartnerSys] ASC,
        [AccessIntegrationSettingEnum] ASC
    )
```

This seems to have solved the problem.  I can insert more than one row, but if I  try to insert a row with a duplicate combination of the two, it throws the error.  I will have to research (or try) each of those settings to find out which one was causing the problem, and why.

Comment: I take it that the constraint already existed, so the second statement should have done absoluty nothing and changed nothing at all. Except when maybe the table also exists in another schema then dbo and somehow you where accesing the table in that other schema

Comment: Yes.  To the final script, I will need to drop the constraint and then re-add it as I want it.